# XAMPP - Apache doesn't run, This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies

Tags: apache, server, xampp, port

I have a problem starting apache.
I use windows 10.

```
12:35:49 [Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:35:49 [Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
12:35:49 [Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:35:49 [Apache] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:35:49 [Apache] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:35:49 [Apache] If you need more help, copy and post this
12:35:49 [Apache] entire log window on the forums
```

I changed port 80 to 8080 and Listen 443 to 444

the file apache_start.bat:

```
@echo off
cd /D %~dp0
echo Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
echo Bitte erst bei einem gewollten Shutdown schliessen
echo Please close this command only for Shutdown
echo Apache 2 is starting ...

apache\bin\httpd.exe

if errorlevel 255 goto finish
if errorlevel 1 goto error
goto finish

:error
echo.
echo Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden
echo Apache could not be started
pause

:finish
```

Executing apache_start.exe

```
Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
Bitte erst bei einem gewollten Shutdown schliessen
Please close this command only for Shutdown
Apache 2 is starting ...

Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden
Apache could not be started
Press any key to continue . . .
```

please help!!

Comment: So, did you _"Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues"_? Not only might that help you find the root cause - it could help us as well.